# Java Dynamic Function Call

Tags: java, reflection, dynamic-function

I have a class

```
class JsonMap extends HashMap<String, Object> {}
```

I initialized an object like this

```
JsonMap jm = new JsonMap();
```

I am inserting data into it like this

```
jm.put("id", 4);
jm.put("message", "Hello");
```

but i want to do something easy like this with same effect.

```
jm.setId(4);
jm.setMessage("Hello");
```

Is this possibe without having to write methods `setId` and `setMessage` in `JsonMap` class?

function name is dynamic: first part is always 'set' and second part is dynamic value. this will go as key inside `HashMap`.

Can anyone show me how to achieve this, if it's possible?

Comment: i don't think that making something like `dynamic methods` or similar to javascript `prototype` is possible in java.

Comment: My question is why would you do that? `jm.put("key","value")` is already very simple in writing

Comment: U also can mess up a little bit and make something like this: http://pastebin.com/MtggQ9Ec but for me it just looks worse than standard `jm.put("key","val");`

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is not possible as **the language does not support this kind of feature**, so at least you can stop looking for a built-in language feature. The alternative options you may want to look at:

- professional JSON serializers (like [Jackson](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/))
- JSONtoPOJO converters (many of these are available [online](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/))

Answer (score 0):

you would need to write methods to do this for you

```
public void setId(int id) {
    jm.put("id", id);
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    jm.put("message", message);
}
```

Comment: whole implementation would be case dependent and he would need to write method for every key he wants to include to JSON object

Comment: @syraz37 Java is a strongly typed language, not a scripting language. `jm.setId(4)` requires that the `setId(int)` method is defined in the class.

Comment: @nLee Given his example, the `setId` method should take an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a strongly typed language, not a scripting language, so **no**, it is not possible without having to write methods `setId` and `setMessage` in the `JsonMap` class.